# Div Highlight on Fancybox Close - Jquery

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am trying to add a setTimeout function on the close of my Fancybox.  When I try this, the code breaks.  Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrect?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".popFrame").fancybox({
'height'    : 600,
'autoScale' : false,
'transitionIn'    : 'elastic',
'transitionOut'   : 'elastic',
'speedIn'     :   600,
'speedOut'      :   200,
'type'  : 'iframe',
'scrolling' : 'no',
'autoDimensions'    :   false,
'width'   :   620,
'hideOnContentClick' : false, 
'onClosed':function(){
$('#hidden').load('file.php');
}
setTimeout(function(){
$("div.color").fadeOut("slow", function () {
$("div.color").remove();
});
}, 
4000);
);
;})
</script>
```

The Error I'm getting is:

```
missing } after property list
[Break On This Error] setTimeout(function(){
```

Comment: What is the error description?

Comment: haha, that would be helpful, let me edit!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had some syntax errors in your code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".popFrame").fancybox({
        'height'    : 600,
        'autoScale' : false,
        'transitionIn'    : 'elastic',
        'transitionOut'   : 'elastic',
        'speedIn'     :   600,
        'speedOut'      :   200,
        'type'  : 'iframe',
        'scrolling' : 'no',
        'autoDimensions'    :   false,
        'width'   :   620,
        'hideOnContentClick' : false, 
        'onClosed':function(){
            $('#hidden').load('file.php');  
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("div.color").fadeOut("slow", function () {
                    $("div.color").remove();
                });
            },4000);
        }
    });

});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: this took away one error, and added another one, but let me see if I can figure it out.  It says `missing ) after argument list`

Comment: Do you have more javascript? Or is what you posted all youre working with?

Comment: I really just wanted to make sure what I am working with is valid, and since what Joey posted appears valid then my problem lies within something else.

Comment: whoops, somehow when I forgot to add the last `});` from your code Joey.  That fixed it.  Sorry for causing more trouble lol.

Comment: Haha, no problem. I'm happy i could help out and provide an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Extra semicolon on this line:

```
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already terminated the `onClosed` function immediately before calling `setTimeout` so you'll get a syntax error. Try moving your `setTimeout` code inside the function

Answer (score 0):

You can use [jsLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to debug stuff like this.  Especially helpful when you have thousands of lines of JS.  Here's what it says for your code (after turning on all the "tolerate" options):

```
Error:
Problem at line 18 character 1: Expected '}' to match '{' from line 3 and instead 
saw 'setTimeout'.
```

setTimeout(function(){

Problem at line 23 character 6: Expected ')' to match '(' from line 3 and instead saw ';'.

4000);

Problem at line 23 character 7: Expected ';' and instead saw ')'.

4000);

Problem at line 24 character 1: Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.

);

Of course, you will want to have your JavaScript code open in an external editor with line numbers when you fix these errors.